# Zooming in close with mixed cached and dynamic services in ArcGIS flex

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-api

I have an application that uses a cached world basemap overlaid with more local and specific data coming from a dynamic map service. It works well for performance, but some users need to see some very detailed information in the dynamic map service.

Is there a technique to allow users to zoom in past the closest scale range of the cached service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add additional levels of detail (lod's) to the configuration, which will allow you to zoom 'beyond' the available levels of the cached base map.  From the Flex Viewer help - look for the  tag in the 'Map content' section toward the bottom of the page :
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapps/flexviewer/help/index.html#/Main_configuration_file/01m300000018000000/

Here is a sample from a modified Flex Viewer:

```
        <lods>
        <!--Custom levels specified to get 'below' the Esri basemaps-->
        <lod resolution="76.4370282850732" scale="288895.277144"/><!-- 11 -->
        <lod resolution="38.2185141425366" scale="144447.638572"/><!-- 12 -->
        <lod resolution="19.1092570712683" scale="72223.819286"/><!-- 13 -->
        <lod resolution="9.55462853563415" scale="36111.909643"/><!-- 14 -->
        <lod resolution="4.77731426794937" scale="18055.954822"/><!-- 15 -->
        <lod resolution="2.38865713397468" scale="9027.977411"/><!-- 16 -->
        <lod resolution="1.19432856685505" scale="4513.988705"/><!-- 17 -->
        <lod resolution="0.597164283559817" scale="2256.994353"/><!-- 18 -->
        <lod resolution="0.298582141647617" scale="1128.497176"/><!-- 19 -->
        <lod resolution="0.1492910708238085" scale="564.248588"/><!-- Custom1 -->
        <lod resolution="0.0746455354119043" scale="282.124294"/><!-- Custom2 -->
        <lod resolution="0.0373227677059522" scale="141.062147"/><!-- Custom3 -->
    </lods>
```